# How do I hide api keys used in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, android-manifest, token

I've seen different ways of hiding api keys in an android app such as https://medium.com/@abhi007tyagi/storing-api-keys-using-android-ndk-6abb0adcadad

That assumes you access the key from a java file.  But what if your keys are in the manifest, such as third party libraries like google maps?

Comment: why do you want to hide it? as you may know, you can restrict the API key to a specific application id (package name) in google console. I guess this is enough for your keys to not be used by another applications

Comment: that was just an example, it could be any api key or secret where the instructions tell you to place it in the manifest.

Comment: I like this solution: https://www.joshmcarthur.com/2014/02/16/keeping-secrets-in-an-android-application.html

Comment: Just see this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473527/how-to-hide-api-keys-in-androidmanifest-xml/72755092#72755092](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473527/how-to-hide-api-keys-in-androidmanifest-xml/72755092#72755092)

Comment: You can see this post : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473527/how-to-hide-api-keys-in-androidmanifest-xml/72755092#72755092](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473527/how-to-hide-api-keys-in-androidmanifest-xml/72755092#72755092)

Comment: You can see this post : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473527/how-to-hide-api-keys-in-androidmanifest-xml/72755092#72755092](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473527/how-to-hide-api-keys-in-androidmanifest-xml/72755092#72755092)