# How to hide API Keys in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, security, flutter, api-key

I've just started [Google Maps plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) for Flutter and it required me to insert the generated API key into the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`. A few moments later I committed it to my repo and immediately got a warning from Google and Git to change generate a new key etc (didn't know you weren't supposed to do that so I'm well aware now).

After, I began searching ways to hide API keys. One solution is to use the [Flutter Secure Storage plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage#-readme-tab-) but that only helps (I think) within a `.dart` file. Another is to create a separate file and add it to .gitignore but when I build the APK won't that file also be bundled?

Ideally I'd like to publish it but I wouldn't want the key to be easily accessible so how can I load the API key into the `AndroidManifest.xml` file without using plaintext? I would like to avoid using a backend so I was thinking I could manually hash it and then unhash at runtime, but I still don't know how to dynamically change the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: instead of locating these service wrappers for 3rd party api's directly in the app, consider a different topology in which services located on servers separate from the app. Its more work but there is not any security issue regarding the keys because u control the server.

Comment: @RobertRowntree I did say I would like to avoid using a backend, i.e a sever. I know it's possible via firebase but I'm still seeking alternatives

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way for you to obfuscate the key stored in your Manifest as the stored (static) value will be directly used by the Google Maps API itself. To secure your key, consider adding restrictions in your GCP console so that only authorized clients can use your key.

See this link for more details: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#restrict_key

Here's more information about the best practices to securing your API keys:
https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#api_key_table

Comment: If I restrict the key in the GCP does this mean I can bundle it with my APK in production?

Comment: @S.Ramjit Yes that's correct. As long as you've configured the restrictions properly, you don't have to worry about unauthorized usages. It's also a good practice to monitor your usage in your GCP console.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late but that can help someone,

Just type :

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${API_KEY}" />
```

See the youtube video for more explain :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8lYNW_Or2o

Best Regard

Comment: when you decompile the apk build and check android manifest file, still you can see the keys clearly visible. so not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Look here: [Hide your api keys from your android manifest file with Flutter using local.properties](https://stevenosse.com/hide-your-api-keys-from-your-android-manifest-file-with-flutter-using-localproperties). Work for React Native, too.